# Hello, I want to sell tokens, it gives me the same error

Tags: error

The contract function "swapExactTokensForTokensSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens" reverted with the following reason: PancakeLibrary: INSUFFICIENT_INPUT_AMOUNT

Answer (score 0):

If you get error "PancakeLibrary: INSUFFICIENT_INPUT_AMOUNT" try to either increase the slippage tolerance in your transaction settings or double check the token amount you are trying to swap, making sure that it matches the token's decimal precision.

fixing this and trying to run the transaction again might help.

Ps, make sure there's enough liquidity in the pool for the token pair you are swapping.